# Exposed filter shs (simple hierarchical select) in a custom template

Tags: 7, views

I don't see anywhere how to print this exposed filter in a custom template.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I did't add `filter-` in front of the filter name. Now it works with:

```
print $widgets['filter-{filter_name}']->widget;
```